# How to put a text box on python figure when the xaxis is a datetime

Tags: python, datetime, textbox, matplotlib

I have made a figure with the x-axis as `datetime` (2012-8-1, 2012-10,7....)

I want to put a textbox to label this figure

`id = ("(A)","(B)","(C)","(D)","(E)","(Average)")`

## X-axis

```
months = mpl.dates.MonthLocator() # every month
days = mpl.dates.DayLocator(interval=5) # every 10 days
dateFmt=mpl.dates.DateFormatter('%m-%d')    
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(dateFmt)
ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(months)
#ax.xaxis.set_minor_locator(days)
ax.xaxis_date()
```

## Y-axis

```
ax.set_ylim(ymin[i],ymax[i])
ax.set_ylabel(ylabels)
ax.axhline(linewidth=0.5,color="k")
ax.yaxis.set_major_locator(tk.MaxNLocator(nbins=3))
ax.yaxis.set_minor_locator(tk.MaxNLocator(nbins=6))
[tickline.set_markersize(3) for tickline in ax.yaxis.get_ticklines(minor=True)]
[tickline.set_markersize(2.5) for tickline in ax.yaxis.get_ticklines(minor=True)]
```

## Text

```
ax.text(0.25,ymax[i],id[i],fontsize=15)
```

But I can't see the labels at all.

How can I realize it?

Comment: You might have stated what library (graphing library??) you're using here.

Comment: guessing you are using matplotlib ...

Comment: What is this `id = ...`-line good for? Is it the desired output? if not, if it'S in your code: please do not hide the built-in id-function. This might have nasty side-effects. It would also be helpful to have a minimal, self-contained example. What values do you have? They might be the reason for your problem...

Answer (score 2):

You need to either enter the x-coordinate in the same format (a date) as for the other plot methods, or *transform* the coordinates. If you want to stick with the x=.25 you could use:

```
ax.text(0.25,ymax[i],id[i], transform=ax.transAxes, fontsize=15)
```

It will place the text at a quarter of the ax's width.

Comment: I think there also needs to be a `plt.draw()`.

Answer (score 0):

An approach is to convert the date to a number and use the number in subsequent calls:

```
dates = matplotlib.dates.date2num([x])
ax.text(dates[0], y, message, color='red')
```

where x is the datetime you want to convert, y is assumed not to be in datetime format but in numerical format, and message contains the string you want to have displayed.